# Questions about the voltages of a lithium jump starter I purchased

Tags: voltage, batteries, lithium-ion, inverter

I purchased an Audew jump starter based on several favorable reviews on youtube.

According to the specs, the jump start output is 14.8V, but when I check the voltage with my multimeter it measures 16.3V.

The jump starter also has a 15V/10A output for a cigarette lighter adapter. The actual voltage for this also measured 16.3 which I guess is no surprise. I tried to power a 150W inverter but the inverter wouldn't even power a 15W device - I'm assuming the inverter can't handle the 16V?

My bigger concern is if it is still safe to use this battery to Jump Start a car? I understand that a car needs greater than 12V to start, but is 16V too much to risk damage?

Comment: This is difficult to answer, as we don't know anything about your devices. Furthermore your question is most probably off-topic because it deals with the use of electronic devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary: The jump start pack voltage of 16V + will drop to around the current battery voltage as soon as it is connected. There is good reason to expect it to be safe to use.** *

---

The following is based on the characteristics of LiIon battery chemistry.
It is extremely likely that the equipment is 'fit for purpose'. As in all such cases, caveat emptor*

The charging device appears to be using 4 x LiIon cells.

A typical Lithium Ion cell has a maximum fully charged voltage of 4.2V.
Anything in the range 4.0 - 4.2V can be considered charged. Lower Vmax leads to longer cycle lifetime in exchange for a moderate reduction in per cycle energy capacity.

A typical cell is quoted as having a nominal voltage of 3.6 ot 3.7 volts. This is the nominal average voltage across a discharge cycle.

So 14.8/4 = 3.7V / cell = expected nominal voltage.

16.3 / 4 = 4.075 V which is inside the 4.0-4.2V range.
This has the advantage of allowing a simpler and safer charge termination system if they choose to use it. It will not noticeably affect charged capacity.

Automotive electronics must be engineered to withstand "things that happen" in a typical automotive electrical system. Voltages over or well over the nominal 13.8V max of the system can happen under certain normal operating conditions.

The jump start pack voltage of 16V + will drop to around the current battery voltage as soon as it is connected. There is good reason to expect it to be safe to use*.

---

**150 W Inverter**

The pack should be able to power a 150 Watt load (about 10 amps)- although it is possible that it will work well as a jump start pack while failing to power such a load.  If the inverter starts on the original 16+V the voltage will usually almost immediately drop to well under 16V under a substantial load. If it operates but does not provide much power, measuring voltages at the source and at the inverter terminals may help assesss why.

This is because most jump starting devices do not do function in the manner that they claim or that they are commionly believed to work. In almost all cases the devices do NOT power the vehicle starter motor directly. Instead, they transfer charge to the "dead" battery, providing it with the ability to return most of this energy in a short period when the next starting attempt is made. This is a fortunate but little appreciated 'feature' of typical lead acid automotive batteries.

I once jump-started a vehicle using 2 x 6V 3 Ah batteries in series, connected by a length of bell wire. This was being used as a camping light supply - which job it did well. Maximum current available at cranking voltages at the end of the bell-wire would have been a few amps. 10 minutes or so trickle charging of the 'dead' battery allowed the vehicle to start. Over decades I have regularly jump-started vehicles using jumper leads and clip connections that would have been wholly incapable of providing cranking level currents directly.

---

*Caveat emptor -> let the buyer beware -> It's your responsibility.

---

[**These diodes**](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?k=diode+10a&k=&pkeyword=diode+10a&sv=0&pv69=329314&pv69=409134&pv69=411897&sf=1&FV=914%7C102511%2C914%7C102532%2C914%7C104759%2C914%7C107648%2C914%7C107663%2C914%7C109759%2C914%7C112161%2C914%7C112165%2C914%7C115884%2C914%7C115889%2C914%7C119415%2C914%7C142049%2C914%7C142062%2C914%7C146217%2C914%7C148963%2C914%7C150172%2C914%7C151539%2C914%7C154440%2C914%7C158363%2C914%7C158377%2C914%7C163154%2C914%7C165320%2C914%7C167362%2C914%7C183493%2C914%7C183499%2C914%7C185126%2C914%7C186219%2C914%7C186220%2C914%7C188170%2C914%7C190274%2C914%7C191765%2C914%7C193820%2C914%7C193827%2C914%7C433486%2C914%7C72441%2C914%7C72471%2C914%7C75955%2C914%7C79876%2C914%7C82045%2C914%7C82660%2C914%7C86826%2C914%7C89062%2C914%7C93448%2C914%7C96664%2C914%7C99242%2C-8%7C280&quantity=1&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&pageSize=25) are potentially suitable. This is a Digikey selector guide of diodes of 10A plus, through hole or stud or plate mount. Unusually in this case you want high forward voltage drop. eg [**These**](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/10A02-T/10A02-TDICT-ND/2242770) cost $US0.64/1  in stock at Digikey and drop 1V at 10A. 1 or 2 in series would drop the voltage initially. A relay or switch across them will allow lower battery voltage operation without loss.  These have the advantage that they do not need heat sinking - but will get very hot at 10A - about 100C rise above ambient! (which they are rated for !).

[**These**](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/10A02-T/10A02-TDICT-ND/2242770) are 64 cents and drop 2V at 10A and need a heatsink.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned in the comments further below... I read the inverter documentation and it has over-voltage protection so it is unable to accept voltage greater than 15V. It appears that I need to find an inverter capable of accepting the 16V initial input.

Comment: @McMath Copying comment info into the question is desirable. || A series diode or maybe two may allow startup at some efficiency loss. || Say 0.8V diode drop in 16V = 5% loss. At not too much extra complexity a relay that adds one or 2 diodes when Vbat is high and drops then out for most of the battery discharge curve  may be not a wholly unnacceptable idea. And arduino, as relay, a relay drive transistor and a few resistors would do the job - or even a comparator in place of the Arduino.

Comment: Thanks, pity most of the low wattage inverters appear to only accept under 15V input. What do you think about powering 12v DC devices directly from the power source? Is it true that most DC devices that can accept a cigarette lighter adapter should be capable of accepting higher initial voltages? The device I really want to power with the jump starter is a 12v 10A portable inflator.

Comment: @McMath For equipment with brushed DC motors you'd expect the motor to usually be "safish" at say 16V. Running hard and long MAY cause issues. You'd expect the battery voltage to drop somewhat almost immediately and also for lead drop to be not insignificant. You'd hope [tm] that people designing equipment for an automotive environment would make them safe for very brief excursions to higher voltages - but sustained operation at 16V is beyond what you'd reasonably expect from a car. ...

Comment: ...  A brushless motor has electronics which you'd (again) hope would be OK at rather above spec (eg maybe 20V FETS - but higher would be 'a very good idea' - but no guarantees. || With a brushless motor you are at the mercy of the controller to treat it safely. || For interest - what are you inflating? 12V x 10A =~ 120 Watts. How would you like a 1000 W inflator?

Comment: Inflatable Kayak and Car tires off top of my head. Audew have a 12V/10A inflator with cigarette lighter plug that I may purchase. The 10A matches the max supplied by the jump starter.

Comment: @McMath Adding some suitably rated series diodes wastes power but may meet your need. Vbat at no load is still 16V until load is applied so may not work. If you can get surplus bridge rectifiers then you get 2S2P arrangement of diodes using DC- as input and DC+ as output so a 5A bridge would do and drop would be around 2V under load.
|| [This](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Converter-10-12-15-20A-150-250-300-400-1200W-Step-up-Step-down-Buck-Boost-/382219150784)  converter from China via ebay LOOKS ideal. Looks. Page down to the $7.78 150W 12A stepdown version "150W 12A Step down Converter"

Comment: Wish I had the skills to put something together, but that's something maybe for the future. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @McMath That ebay converter for $7.78 will probably do what you want - if that's of interest advise and I can look closer. OR series diodes as I suggested are a cheap and nasty but potentially effective way of reducing voltage.

Comment: Would that 150W 12A stepdown be all I need... so I would connect the battery to that converter and then from the converter to the device I would like to power? What voltage range would be brought down to the 12V? Also, if that device works as described, could you suggest a housing solution? Thanks

Comment: [Is this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Converter-Regulator-24V-Step-Down-to-12V-10A-120W-Regulator-US-STOCK/223779854047?hash=item341a5196df:g:ZdwAAOSwCbtZza4z) basically the same thing? It claims to have input voltage of 15-30V. But what happens when the input voltage drops to under 15V, will it still work?

Comment: @McMath  No - the step down unit must function across the total battery range - in your case ( 3 to 4.2V/cell x 4 = 12 - 16.8V. || The version I suggested says: Input voltage: 4.5-32V.
Output voltage: 1-30V continuously adjustable (the default is adjusted to 5V).|| Output max will be somewhat below Vin - see spec sheet. Vout is settable with a control (usually potentiometer)

Comment: @McMath They do NOT say what the minimum Vin-Vout value is. They do Say Vinmax = 32V and Voutmax is 30V - suggesting a 2V difference - and hopefully somewhat less. This means battery MAY not get wholly discharged - not much capacity at bottom end so nit a great problem. 

tHEY DO not SAY WHAT THE MINIMUM vIN-vOUT VALUE O

Comment: If I use the dirty method by just connecting a diode or multiple diodes, can you show me what diode would be needed for safe usage and how many. Thanks

Comment: Russell, thanks for all the suggestions. When I have spare time I'll try the first solution you proposed - the diode and the relay. I think I will try the inflator direct with the battery pack before anything else.

Comment: Rusell, would [this](https://www.amazon.com/Converter-12V-Automatic-Waterproof-Transformer/dp/B07X9Y5MXT?th=1) be a 1 step solution? I probably won't go this route, but I'm interested if this product would be an easy way to regulate the voltage even when it drops from the 16.3V. Thanks

Comment: @McMath Yes, that's a one step solution(assuming it works as claimed). Looks nice. Buck boost is the ideal as it covers the whole battery range if you run directly from the battery. If so do note that you must not run the batteries under 3V/cell (12V for 4) and ideally about 3.2v/cell. (You can go under 4V but there is a bout zilch energy left and it takes a bit off the lifetime each time you do it). .

Comment: I just saw the link to the diodes you referenced. so the idea is that when the voltage is initially high the circuit will go through the diodes and then when the voltage drops below a threshold, then a relay will open another circuit and close the circuit with the diodes - is that the general idea? I have never tinkered with circuits, but when I have time I may start. Is there a specific relay I would purchase rated for say 15V? Or do I need some type of controller for the relay?

Comment: I think I also misunderstood  your original reference to that Ebay $7.78 converter - I thought I would need to attach a potentiometer to set the voltage, but it appears that one is on the board and that I could adjust the output voltage with a small screw driver - is that correct?

Comment: @McMath Yes - adjustment included. Also maybe a current limit (without relooking). Not as flexible as the buck-boost - nut a lot cheaper. There will be cheaper buckboosts on ebay. Do not overdischarge your battery! It will (probably) not catch fire but it will shorten its life.

Comment: Russell, I bought a [this step up device](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-USB-to-DC-9V-12V-Step-Up-Converter-for-Power-Bank-Laptop-Tablet-Router-CCTV/152632623247?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) and just tested it with my 9V 700mA desk fan.... when connected to an Aukey power bank via one of the USB 2.1A outlets, the fan runs well. But when I connect the fan to the 2.1A outlet of the Audew jump Starter, it spins for a second and then nothing. Any idea what the likely reason could be?

Comment: The USB outlets of both power supplies - the Anker power bank and Audew jump Starter are the 5V/2.1A variety.

Comment: @McMath New question really AND not enough data for more than hopefully good guesses. It MIGHT be that either the fan Istartup is too high or the fan Irun too low for the source. As both supplies are of same nominal spec there is a fair chance that the answer is "Both companies found a no-ish name band device in China and badge engineered it and one suppy's design is a more accommodating one". Try MORE load and(less likely) a SMALL series R.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the specs, the jump start output is 14.8V, but when I check the voltage with my multimeter it measures 16.3V.

This is fine. What they quoted you is the nominal voltage of four 3.7V Li-ion cells in series. Such a battery is expected to have an open-circuit voltage of about 16.4V fully charged, dropping to around 15.2V at 80% charge and 14.8V somewhere around the middle of discharge. The voltage under load will be lower than those, depending on the load (but Li-ions have some amazing current capacity, so maybe not a whole lot!)

> I tried to power a 150W inverter but the inverter wouldn't even power a 15W device - I'm assuming the inverter can't handle the 16V?

I have encountered some inverters with this issue, yes. They have overvoltage protection circuitry, which is good, but it's a little bit too eager. If the inverter actually started pulling current from the battery, the voltage would probably drop down to a level that would make the protection circuitry happy, but since it never starts up, that never happens.

> My bigger concern is if it is still safe to use this battery to Jump Start a car? I understand that a car needs greater than 12V to start, but is 16V too much to risk damage

There's no problem. First, car electrical systems are known for some quite large voltage swings, and anything connected to them will be designed for that. Second, the car battery is bigger and badder than your jumpstart pack, and if it's dead, that means its terminal voltage is pretty low. The dead battery will do a much better job of pulling the system voltage down than the jumpstart battery will do of pulling it up, and the jumpstart battery (since it's much smaller), will be dead long before it can pull the car battery up anywhere near 16V.

Comment: I think you're right....after reading the inverter documentation, it has over-voltage protection... the input voltage range is limited to between 11-15V. So it looks like I would need a different inverter that is capable of accepting, at least momentarily, a voltage of just over 16v. Any idea where I could find such an inverter - I need it to power only about 60W max.

Comment: Also, do you think the jump starter would be capable of powering a 12V/10A DC inflator, direct from the cigarette lighter adapter?

Answer (score 0):

The voltage of a battery drops under load due to internal resistance. Imagine having a series resistor of 0.1 Ω with a 16 V battery. Drawing 10 A would drop the voltage to 15 V; a starter motor drawing 50 A would leave just 11 V, which is acceptable for turning over an automotive engine. Note also that ~250 W of heat (50 A at 5 V) would be dissipated in the 0.1 Ω resistor (i.e. the internal resistance of the battery). Do that for *long*, and the battery would be toast.

As for operating a 1500 W inverter, drawing 125 A, if your battery did not have some internal protective circuit, it would have destroyed itself... with Li batteries, rather violently.

Voltage should be measured both open circuit (OC, no load) **and under the expected load**.

Comment: Inverter is 150 watt - not 1500.